# PHP code for insert checkbox value into spesific column on mysql with select form

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I need help php code to identify my checkbox value insert in to some spesific coloumn, my form like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="A" Value="Animal">Animal <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="B" Value="Ball">Ball <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="C" Value="Champ">Champ <br/>

<label for="select">Category</label>
<select name="select" size="1">
<option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
<option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
<option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

i need if select category 1 and make submit the checkbox value will insert in to table column "cat1" and i select category 2 and make submit the checkbox value will insert in to table column "cat2".
table = id, cat1, cat2, cat3

Comment: Can someone please make a permanent link to a "checkbox tutorial for dummys" for all those posts like this one? Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you have tried with your php/mysql code. We can help troubleshoot, but we don't want to write it for you.

Comment: Please tell us what method do you use to submit form. Is it get or post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this php code

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('myTable');
$val = array();
if (isset($_POST['A']))
    $val[] = $_POST['A'];
if (isset($_POST['B']))
    $val[] = $_POST['B'];
if (isset($_POST['C']))
    $val[] = $_POST['C'];
$value = implode(', ', $val);
if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
    $col = $_POST['select'];
    if ($col == 'Category 1') {
        $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO myTable(cat1) VALUES($value)');
    }
    else if ($col == 'Category 2') {
        $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO myTable(cat2) VALUES($value)');
    }
    else if ($col == 'Category 3') {
        $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO myTable(cat3) VALUES($value)');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: im newbie with php and mysql. but i try combine with other code from here too. It works. thanks for ur help.