# Two or more different checkboxes how to store value in database

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a form with text and number input fields and then there are also some checkboxes. 
I can get the text into the database from the input fields, but I can not get it to work with checkboxes, when I have more than 1. Here is the code of 2 out of the 4 I have in my form.

```
    <dl class="inputCheckbox">
        <dt><label for="interests">Nyt/brugt:</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" name="newUsed[]" value="Nyt" />
            <label for="new" class="opt">Nyt</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="newUsed[]" value="Brugt" />
            <label for="used" class="opt">Brugt</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="newUsed[]" value="Nyt/Brugt" />
            <label for="both" class="opt">Nyt/Brugt</label>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="inputCheckbox">
        <dt><label for="interests">Diverse:</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" name="various[]" value="El" />
            <label for="electricity" class="opt">El</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="various[]" value="Vand" />
            <label for="water" class="opt">Vand</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="various[]" value="El/Vand" />
            <label for="both" class="opt">El/Vand</label>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

I hope that there are some who can help me with some PHP code :)

Here's the code of how I got the other things like text and number from the label into the database.

```
<?php

session_start();

include('connection.php');
$cvr=$_POST['cvr'];
$cvr=$_POST['companyName'];
$fName=$_POST['fName'];
$lName=$_POST['lName'];
$streetName=$_POST['streetName'];
$streetNumber=$_POST['streetNumber'];
$zip=$_POST['zip'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$eMail=$_POST['eMail'];
$repeatEmail=$_POST['repeatEmail'];
$locationNumber=$_POST['locationNumber'];
$size=$_POST['size'];
$products=$_POST['products'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$newUsed=$_POST['newUsed'];
$various=$_POST['various'];
$sleep=$_POST['sleep'];
$reOrder=$_POST['reOrder'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO creatUser(cvr, fName, lName, streetName, streetNumber, zip, city, phone, eMail, repeatEmail, locationNumber, size, products, comments)
    VALUES('$cvr', '$fName', '$lName', '$streetName', '$streetNumber', '$zip', '$city', '$phone', '$eMail', '$repeatEmail', '$locationNumber', '$size', '$products', '$comments')");

header("location: creatUser.php?remarks=success");

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You... aren't doing anything with $various or $newUsed. This is an array by the way, so you need to process the data for the DB.

Comment: There are dozens of questions of this type on Stack Overflow.  Also, your SQL is wide open to SQL injection http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP code for insert checkbox value into spesific column on mysql with select form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062410/php-code-for-insert-checkbox-value-into-spesific-column-on-mysql-with-select-for)

Comment: Also, please stop using `mysql_*`. It is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can save checkboxes in a comma separated format.

In you PHP script you can do

```
$checkboxData = implode(",", $_POST['various']);
```

When repopulating your data you can do in your view

```
<?php $checkboxValues = explode(",", $checkboxData); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="various[]" value="El" <?php if(in_array("EL", $checkboxValues)) echo 'selected="selected";?>/>
```

Comment: I am glad that there is such a quick reply to me, thank you. Unfortunately, I am quite new in php and coding.

So I do not really understand what it is I should do, maybe there was someone who could write exactly what it is that I need to write.

Sorry if there are some who feel this issue has been here often, unfortunately I have not been able to find one where it was about several different checkboxes. sorry.

Comment: You have checkboxes in your form that you want to save in database. In my answer the first code block shows how you can save all these checkboxes in a comma separated format. For example, if you select EL and Vand checkboxes you will get an array in `$_POST['various']`. This array contains selected checkbox values. So, by using `$checkboxData = implode(",", $_POST['various']);` code you will get a string like EL,Vand in your database table field, for example say varios.

Comment: Then when you want to edit same form with same selected checkbox values, you will query database and you have to show the `EL` and `Vand` checkboxes selected. You will get a string like `EL,Vand` from database and then you can separate these values by using `<?php $checkboxValues = explode(",", $checkboxData); ?>` code in your form file.
Then you can actually decide whether this checkbox should be checked or not based on the values you save in database by using `<input type="checkbox" name="various[]" value="El" <?php if(in_array("EL", $checkboxValues)) echo 'selected="selected";?>/>`

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, it has helped a lot in understanding what is going on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,

```
 $various=$_POST['various'];

 $VariousData ='';
 foreach($various as $k=>$val){
   $VariousData .=$val." ";
 }
```

You can use to store `$VariousData` into your table

Comment: Why wouldn't you just serialize() the array? It preserves the data more accurately.

Comment: Because storing serialized data to an SQL database is the source of all evil and suffering in the universe.

Comment: @kinghfb There will be some overhead compared to `implode()`ing the string (namely the array description bit which tells `serialize()` this is an array with some items) - about 4 bytes at head and tail and 2 bytes (?) for each item.

Comment: @TimothyChoi Check out a book called SQL Antipatterns, it explains better than I could.  Long story short, if you want to store a variable number of values for a row in a particular table, they should be stored as rows in a dependant table, not as serialized or comma separated strings.  It violates 1NF and removes many of the benefits of using an SQL based database in the first place

Comment: @GordonM True, but it depends what you're doing with the data. Not everything requires an additional table, especially if you have no intention of searching or sorting it. In OP's case, I suppose, your argument makes sense.

Comment: @GordonM If it gets the job done, why not? Given the checkbox options are static, there is no point in over-normalizing the table. It only generates an extra query.

Comment: @TimothyChoi The number of times I've had to debug systems that had been written like that because the original developer "wanted to avoid an extra query"...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to serialize the checkbox inputs in some way. Usually `explode()` and `implode()` is used for this. Using your code:

```
$newUsedSerialized = implode(",", $_POST["newUsed"]); # Sanitize $_POST["newUsed"] first!
```

Then, get your inputs back into an array with

```
$newUsedArray = explode(",", $queryResult["newUsed"]);
```

And so you can use `$newUsedArray` in your PHP code for generating the forms:

```
$inputField = "";
$inputField .= '<input type="checkbox" name="newUsed[]" checked="' . (in_array("Nyt", $nytUsedArray) ? "checked" : "") . '/>';
```

(In this case, consider the use of numerical `values` instead - it saves space.)

Comment: @user3069468 Edited with a better example.